AMD processor specs?
I was considering switching to AMD processors, but I hit a road block, I can not find product specifications for many of their processors.
For example, a search for [CENSORED TO PREVENT OFF-TOPIC CLOSE] site:amd.com yields stuff like press releases.
Where are the AMD product specs for ECC, or NUMA support, for example? https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors.html does not give this information.
How do I find out what suits my needs with AMD processors?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs. WOW, yeah, what are you talking about, that is exactly what I am doing: Where are the AMD product specs? I.E. How to find out what suits my needs. The contradiction in the closed as off-topic could not be more obvious.

Close reasons are canned, pre-written. This question could have been closed for several reasons, not least of which are the you are asking us to play Google for you. Either these specifications are published or they are not. You aren't trying to solve a technical problem here, which is what this site is about. You are asking us to find information for you.

@music2myear Uh, I already did a search, that is why I am here. Either way, an answer from google that was not from AMD would not be relevant to my question. I want the information from AMD. I find it hard to believe that AMD would not publish useful information on all their processors.

That does not fix the problem of this being off topic here. SuperUser is not a search assistant service, and if you're specifically looking for AMD-sourced information, you have just as much access to that as we do. Either AMD publishes that info, or they don't. SuperUser is not a place to find AMD insiders who can divulge information has not published officially.

I can not find product specifications for many of their processors.
The FX-8370 spec can be found at AMD FX-Series FX-8370 - FD8370FRW8KHK / FD8370FRHKBOX / FD8370FRHKHBX.
It does not support ECC (see AMD FX-8370 Specs | TechPowerUp CPU Database

Huge trust issues, for example AMD lists at most the processor extensions: AES , AVX , FMA4.  Yet the website you provide lists SSE and over a dozen other extensions. So one must be listing bad information AMD or cpu-world.com

Both the websites I linked list the same extensions. Why don't you ask AMD?

And hundreds of websites clone wikipedia, does that make it truth, no. AMD has no contact info for regular consumers.

Also AMD microarchitecture documentation says that FX-Series DO have ECC (though it is hard to tell what 'Model 00h-0Fh` exactly refers to). So yet another apparent contradiction.

As for AMD community outreach the question has already been asked
